# How to reference the resources of a library in a library?

Tags: android-resources, android-library

Let me give a simple example.
An Android Studio project has two modules:

```
MyApp
MyLibrary
```

MyApp is an Android app and MyLibrary is an Android library used by MyApp. IMPORTANT:MyLibrary is a module with all the source code. It is a project inside this project.

Here is the mystery. Both MyApp and MyLibrary use the following library:

```
libraryfoo.aar
```

libraryfoo.aar is in the `libs` folder of both modules.
However, MyApp's build.gradle has the following:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
```

while MyLibrary's build.gradle has the following:

```
compileOnly files('libs/libraryfoo.aar')
```

This is because direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR.
librarryfoo has a string value foo. In a layout XML file of MyApp, the following works:

```
android:text="@string/foo"
```

However, the same code in a layout file of MyLibrary results in error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol '@string/foo'
```

Could anyone offer a tip to help remedy this problem?